# What does the last part of a Google Drive read-only file URL mean?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I have a Google drive URL that is

> https://docs.google.com/file/d/0AwlAqojdgwiCNW5ZcnZYSXB0eW8/image?pagenumber=1&w=800

Can someone please explain what the part

```
0AwlAqojdgwiCNW5ZcnZYSXB0eW8/image?pagenumber=1&w=800
```

means? I am building something that connects to the Google Drive but I need to know what this part is.
EDIT:
The initial 13 characters are the user id constant for a user

Comment: There is an [SDK for Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/). Perhaps this is question is better for the developer forums there.

Comment: There is no such thing that a "id constant for a user"

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

The part after the last slash of a file's URL that is hosted in Google Drive of Google Editors could vary depending if the URL has the purpose to be used to share the file to someone without a Google account, the format to be used to publish the content to the web and include parameters to modify how the content will be published or displayed.

## Additional details

Instead of filenames for URL Google Drive and Docs editors uses a "file key" so if the user changes the filename the URL still works.

The "file key" is between the last two slashes [/]. The part after the last slash could vary depending if the URL has the purpose to share the file to someone without a Google account, the format to be used i.e. to publish the content to the web and include parameters to modify how the content will be published or displayed.

`/view` for previewing a file in a web browser
`/preview` for embedding file in a HTML web page
`/edit` for editing a file
`/pubhtml` is used when a document, spreadsheet or slide is published to the web.
`/pub` is used when a drawing is published as image

## Notes

For web site hosting is possible to use filenames in URLs but this require that file are in a public folder.

## References

[Publish web site content - Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/publish-site)

Answer (score -1):

That is called encryption. It is purposely done so for better security, like for example say you had a master username & password list in Google drive and it would look like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/file/master-username&password-list.doc
```

Then one would easily want to get a hold of that file. Although not all Google drive files are yet fully encrypted, this is a false Window feature that already hides the basic title information. The URL also appears to stay the same regardless of Public or Private sharing between users. However, you can use hyperlinks to shorten the URL into a word.

Here you can read more about Google Drive [encryption](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13578_3-57594171-38/google-tests-encryption-to-protect-users-drive-files-against-government-demands/).

Comment: Yeah @Rudolph I agree but I don't think its encryption. It's some kind of hashing where the *initial* 13 characters are User id and the rest are some thing else. I want to know what else?